# Why the picture is showing in half while I am converting dvi to pdf?

Tags: floats, dvipdf

Respected Everyone.

Hello. I am not a beginner as well as not so expert also. Past few months I am writing a book in latex. It is an MCQ problem book in mathematics for which I am using latex software ( Winedt and MikTex). Now here is the problem I faced since last two days.

I have installed recently the latest MikTex complete version (32 Bit) in my computer. After I installed it, some problem has arrived in the figures of my book.

The thing is, I am compiling the book as ctrl+shift+X to dvi format and then converting to "dvi to pdf" format.

While I am doing so, each and every picture in pdf is getting half cut. means half of the portion of each picture is not being shown, the other half is shown.

I have tried my best to figure out what is problem but in vain.

I know I am supposed to provide the file template here but since the file is huge and I am unable to find out where is the mistake, would some one please suggest me what to do ? Should I provide the file completely here so that you can download it and check in your system ?

Please tell me what to do.

*Edit 1*

After the advice, I provide here the minimal example what I am suffering:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Picture}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.28]{gamma_3d}\captionof{figure}{Gamma Function: 3D} \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Although I do not know how to upload the picture "gamma_3d" which is saved in my laptop as in .ps format.

Please feel free to edit the file if necessary.

I tried my best to show the problem. Now its your advice

Comment: Please read http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that for some hints how to produce a minimal working example.  The basic idea is to make the file smaller in steps and see whether the error remains at each step.

Comment: @jarauh I tried my best to provide the file and commands as well. Please let me know your opinion.

Comment: Good, that looks really minimal now.  A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).  You could try to upload the figure elsewhere and link it.

Comment: Try putting an \fbox{...} around the image (just the image).  It also helps to run \usepackage{showframe} when debugging these sorts of things.  BTW, I have no problem using images from the mwe package.